# Create a Script to Scan All Pages of a Website for Cookies

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, cookies

I'm trying (and failing) to create a JS script that will allow me to run a search on every page of my site so that it can tell me what cookies exist on my website.

What am I looking for?

I want to:

1. Get the names of every cookie on my website
2. Save the name of each cookie in phpMyAdmin (using PHP)

This is proving way too difficult for me, and I was wondering if there's a JS script that can do this.

Thanking you all in advance,
Jaymes

Comment: If your page has cookies it must mean you set them somewhere, so why not save them the moment you create them? Also, what is the use case of this?

Comment: Hi mate, I'm working on WordPress and I'm looking to create a list with all the cookies that appear on my site. This includes cookies added via Google (Google Analytics, etc.). I tried to use a plugin to scan for cookies but the plugin didn't provide me with a list with all the cookies. Also, not all cookies are added manually.

Comment: Should've added the WordPress tag then.

Comment: Show what you tried so far and what is exactly not working.